# cordova-sms-plugin not asking for permission

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I think I have cordova-sms-plugin working, if I add this

```
sendSms: function() {
        var number = document.getElementById('numberTxt').value.toString(); /* iOS: ensure number is actually a string */
        var message = document.getElementById('messageTxt').value;
        console.log("number=" + number + ", message= " + message);

        //CONFIGURATION
        var options = {
            replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
            android: {
                intent: ''  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
                //intent: '' // send SMS without opening any other app
            }
        };

        var success = function () { alert('Message sent successfully'); };
        var error = function (e) { alert('Message Failed:' + e); };
        sms.send(number, message, options, success, error);
        //$window.sms.send(number, message, intent, success, error);
    }
```

And taking away the 'INTENT' I have the app telling me the user is denying permission. The docs have something saying about asking permssion but when I add this it doesnt work.

Where or how do I ask permission?

Comment: is your problem for iOS, Android, or another platform?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed, I added this to the android.json

```
  {
          "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS\" />",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.READ_SMS\" />",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.SEND_SMS\" />",
          "count": 1
        }
```

Comment: I dont know why your answer was down voted because it worked for me. So I have given you +1 which cancelled the negative vote.