# Cordova plugin is not showing permission dialog

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, permissions

I'm writing a cordova plugin (clone of the existing device plugin), the java (android) code requires access to device's serial number with [getSerial method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build#getSerial()).
this method requires the following android permissions:

> READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE

> READ_PHONE_STATE

The problem is that when i run the app, it dosen't show the permissions dialog (it not grunt so), but i can grant it with Android setting (Settings -> Apps -> Permissions)

In plugin's plugin.xml file i added: (the enitire plugin.xml file is below)

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
</config-file>
```

In the main config.xml file i added: (the enitire plugin.xml file is below)

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

PS:
I read these 2 questions, and followed their instructions, but it dosent work for me:
[Cordova App 'Android permission Cordova plugin' is not showing permission dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371495/cordova-app-android-permission-cordova-plugin-is-not-showing-permission-dialog)

[cordova-sms-plugin not asking for permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822869/cordova-sms-plugin-not-asking-for-permission)

The entire files:

> plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" id="cordova-plugin-device" version="2.0.4-dev">
<name>Device</name>
<description>Cordova Device Plugin</description>
<license>Apache 2.0</license>
<keywords>cordova,device</keywords>
 <repo>https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git</repo>
<issue>https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB/component/12320648</issue>
<js-module src="www/device.js" name="device">
  <clobbers target="device" />
</js-module>
<!-- android -->
 <platform name="android">
   <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="Device">
         <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device"/>
      </feature>
   </config-file>
   <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
   </config-file>
<source-file src="src/android/Device.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/device" />
</platform>
<!-- ios -->
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="Device">
          <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>
    <header-file src="src/ios/CDVDevice.h" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/CDVDevice.m" />
</platform>
<!-- windows -->
<platform name="windows">
    <js-module src="src/windows/DeviceProxy.js" name="DeviceProxy">
       <runs />
    </js-module>
</platform>
<!-- browser -->
<platform name="browser">
  <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
    <feature name="Device">
      <param name="browser-package" value="Device" />
    </feature>
  </config-file>
  <js-module src="src/browser/DeviceProxy.js" name="DeviceProxy">
      <runs />
  </js-module>
</platform>
<!-- osx -->
<platform name="osx">
  <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
    <feature name="Device">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice"/>
    </feature>
  </config-file>
  <header-file src="src/osx/CDVDevice.h" />
  <source-file src="src/osx/CDVDevice.m" />
</platform>
</plugin>
```

> config.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
        <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
        <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-country" spec="^1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="plg/cordova-plugin-device-master" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.1.4" />
</widget>
```

Comment: I am also looking for the solution . Have you fixed that issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately, Not yet